# SQL Query getting the date between expiration date and effective date from 2 different tables

Tags: sql

I having this problem with query these two table do not have any link between and I am trying to combine. Table 1 have effective and expiration date in which have to be tied to table 2 of PollDate. PollDate must not lies in between the effective and expiration date.

```
Table 1
ClientID    EffectiveDate       ExpirationDate
1       2009-04-01 00:00:00.000 2009-12-18 00:00:00.000
1       2010-02-12 00:00:00.000 2010-03-05 00:00:00.000
1       2010-05-18 00:00:00.000 NULL
1       2009-12-21 00:00:00.000 2010-02-08 00:00:00.000
1       2010-12-19 00:00:00.000 2009-12-20 00:00:00.000

Table 2
ClientID    PollDate
1       2009-12-20 00:00:00.000
1       2009-12-19 00:00:00.000
1       2010-02-12 00:00:00.000
1       2010-02-27 00:00:00.000
1       2010-05-19 00:00:00.000
1       2010-05-29 00:00:00.000
1       2010-05-30 00:00:00.000
1       2010-05-31 00:00:00.000
1       2010-06-05 00:00:00.000
1       2010-06-25 00:00:00.000
1       2010-06-27 00:00:00.000
1       2010-07-02 00:00:00.000
1       2010-08-04 00:00:00.000
1       2010-08-20 00:00:00.000

Result
ClientID    inValidDate
1       2009-12-20 00:00:00.000
1       2009-12-19 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: A bit confused by ".. they do not have any link between them"  Are they not in the same database? Are you looking for a RPC option of some sort?

Comment: No.. they are in the same database. what i meant by link is that both table dont have any reference to each other ie: foreign key. the common domination of both tables are the clientID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a slight variation of @AJP's result - just accounting for NULL values in `ExpirationDate`:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
    [ClientID] INT,
    [EffectiveDate] DATETIME,
    [ExpirationDate] DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #Table1
(
    [ClientID],
    [EffectiveDate],
    [ExpirationDate]
)
SELECT 1, '2009-04-01', '2009-12-18' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-02-12', '2010-03-05' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-05-18', NULL UNION
SELECT 1, '2009-12-21', '2010-02-08' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-12-19', '2009-12-20'

CREATE TABLE #Table2
(
    [ClientID] INT,
    [PollDate] DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #Table2
(
    [ClientID],
    [PollDate]
)
SELECT 1, '2009-12-20' UNION
SELECT 1, '2009-12-19' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-02-12' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-02-27' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-05-19' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-05-29' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-05-30' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-05-31' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-06-05' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-06-25' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-06-27' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-07-02' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-08-04' UNION
SELECT 1, '2010-08-20'

SELECT
    t2.[ClientID],
    t2.[PollDate] AS 'inValidDate'
FROM
    #Table1 AS t1
JOIN
    #Table2 AS t2
ON
    (t2.[PollDate] < t1.[EffectiveDate]
OR  t2.[PollDate] > ISNULL(t1.[ExpirationDate], '9999-12-31'))
AND t1.ClientID = t2.ClientID -- Not clear from your question if this is necessary
```

Comment: If you wanted to include all `NULL` values in `ExpirationDate` you can use `t2.[PollDate] > ISNULL(t1.[ExpirationDate], '1753-01-01'))` instead

Comment: Thanks diaho, this is what need. your query resulting all list of matching PollDates within effectivedate and expiration date. All i need to add is where they both is null so exclude the PollDates that is not lies between both dates.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about syntext but u want to do something like this.

```
select clientID, polDate as 'inValidDate'
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t2.PolDate not in between t1.EffectiveDate and t1.ExpirationDate
```

EDIT:
Assuming if expiration date is null means policy will never expire.

```
select clientID, polDate as 'inValidDate'
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t2.PolDate not in between t1.EffectiveDate and ISNULL(t1.ExpirationDate, '2999-01-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

can u try:

```
select t2.ClientID, t2.PoolDate
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
where t2.PollDate between t1.EffectiveDate and t1.ExpirationDate
```

because u didn't put in the join condition, each row of table1 will match with each row of table2

Comment: i thought he said "PollDate must not lies in between the effective and expiration date". isn't your query will result in between?

Comment: but the sample result from the question is showing "invalid date"